# Where can I find network connection details?

Tags: 12.04, networking

My internet connections works well, but where can i find it's configuration files?

I tried to find it here:
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/NetworkManager
but, there is nothing relevant to my eth0 connection.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you specifically looking for?

Comment: I would like to see connection parameters. If uses dhcp, DNS server, etc...

Comment: Are you using the GUI (GNOME/Unity/etc.), or server/commandline only?

Comment: The first one. Unity especially

Comment: give me a few minutes to deploy a destructable VM so I can graphically show you what to do.  As for determining DHCP/Static, that isn't usually revealed by the network/router unless you ahve admin on that router/network.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you are using the GUI, I thought I'd show you how to do this through Unity.

When you use Unity, the networking stuff is handled by Network Manager.  There is a GUI method to access the connection details.

(1) Click on the connection icon on the top bar.  It may look like a plug, or parallel arrows, if you're using Ethernet and not Wifi.  Left click it.
[image]

(2) Then, you click "Connection Information".
[image]

(3) When you click that, a window with connection information will show up.  It will look similar to this.  Note that I'm on WiFi so the information you have MAY NOT MATCH exactly.
[image]

This will contain information INCLUDING the DNS servers used, the IP your computer has (NOTE: This will be whatever DHCP/ISP/Source of the IP address sets, not necessarily your public IP.), and other information.

You did mention that you wanted to tell if it's DHCP or static.  Unfortunately, unless you know how your network is set up, you can't easily tell whether the IP your computer receives is static or dynamic or DHCP-assigned.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that this information is stored in some files. Where are they placed? Furthermore i found out that "Default Route" in this table is the same as DHCP server, which show me windows ipconfig(Is it right?)

Comment: I don't have Windows around, can't help you with comparison between them.  Default route usually means the default gateway though.  As for where this data is stored, I don't think it is stored anywhere, I believe the data's running from memory and the system itself, rather than being stored anywhere.  Why *specifically* do you want the file if any of where this information is stored?

Comment: It's just for my interest. Is it difficult to find it out?

Comment: @madox2 if all you're interested is seeing the information, just use the GUI, because network manager kind of doesn't really use any textual files to list the configuration.  Those textual files you looked at are good if you don't really use networkmanager.  network manager kind of messes with all of that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for information and for your interest!